# How do I check if a type implements a trait when implementing a proc macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to create a `proc-macro` to derive and implement a trait for structs and I need that all fields within the struct implement `Display`.

How do I check that?

And furthermore how do I check if an attribute implements `Iterator` as well? (I want to handle if the item of the iterator implements display too).

I'm using `syn` and `quote` crates. And I managed to parse my `struct` and generate the implementation. But for types like `Vec` and `Option` I would like to check if they implement `Iterator` and handle it properly.

The `syn::Field` struct has the `ty` attribute which I believe should be a starting point, but looking into the docs I couldn't guess any way to check if this type implements a certain trait.

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible. AFAIK, `syn` gives you the _syntax_ of the source code, not its detailed _semantics_.

Comment: @rodrigo how does serde makes sure every field implements serialize when you derive it?

Comment: It doesn't, serde generates code that *assumes* all the fields implement `Serialize`. It will trigger a compiler error if that's not the case.

Comment: When you `#[derive(Debug)]` on a generic struct `S<T>`, how does Rust know to only derive the implementation when `T: Debug`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Looking at the expanded code clarifies that: it generates bounds like `impl<T: Debug> Debug for S<T>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add trait bounds and/or [static assertions](https://docs.rs/static_assertions/latest/static_assertions/index.html) to the generated code. Macros run before type information is available since they can affect type information.

Comment: A code sample would be very useful for this answer!